# Checking Multiple checkboxes using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, ternary-operator

In my application I am using a single checkbox to 'Select All' other checkboxes. And below is my code snippet which works for me. But I need a shorter method to reduce my code lines.

```
$('#CheckAll').change(function(){   
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {                                       
                    $('.checkboxes').each(function(){                                   
                        $(this).prop("checked", true);                      
                    });
                }
                else{               
                    $('.checkboxes').each(function(){                                   
                        $(this).prop("checked", false);                                                 
                    });             
                }               
            });
```

Is there any easier way to achieve this  using "Ternary Operator".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w3gQJ/474/)

```
$("#CheckAll").click(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Not a big deal.. but when you check all > uncheck (example) 2, check all stays checked :)

Comment: @ManojDhiman also.. not a big deal.. you have 3 same id's :p change to class.. is easy :p

Answer (score 4):

If you *really* want to use a ternary operator ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/razfpcke/)):

```js
$('#CheckAll').change(function () {
    ($(this).is(":checked") ? $('.checkboxes').prop("checked", true) :    $('.checkboxes').prop("checked", false))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='CheckAll'> Check all
<br><br>
<input type='checkbox' class='checkboxes'>
<input type='checkbox' class='checkboxes'>
<input type='checkbox' class='checkboxes'>
<input type='checkbox' class='checkboxes'>
```

---

However, you could just make it shorter by using the selector to (un)select the checkbox:

```js
$('#CheckAll').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('.checkboxes').prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $('.checkboxes').prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='CheckAll'>Check all
<br>
<br>
<input type='checkbox' class='checkboxes'>
<input type='checkbox' class='checkboxes'>
<input type='checkbox' class='checkboxes'>
<input type='checkbox' class='checkboxes'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
   $('#CheckAll').change(function(){   
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {                                       
                        $('.checkboxes').prop("checked", true);                      

                    }
                    else{               
                        $('.checkboxes').prop("checked", false);                                                        
                    }               
                });
```

Comment: Please check the double dot in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var chks = $('.checkboxes'); // cache all once
  $('#CheckAll').change(function(e) {
    chks.prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#CheckAll').change(function(){
    $('.checkboxes').prop("checked",$(this).prop("checked"));
});
```